# Exporting comments and rating from User Generated Content

Tags: 2011, ugc

A client has asked about the ability for them to export UGC comments and ratings into a spreadsheet from Tridion.

After checking the docs and investigation in and around the Control Room dashboard and UGC nodes in Shortcuts and under Publications I can't see anyway to do this within the GUI.

Is that correct - this export functionality is not available (unless we write something for them)?

Answer (score 7):

My understanding is that Excel supports oData natively. I think that you just need to provide the oData endpoint for UGC in order to get the UGC data like comments and ratings (item stats) into Excel.

Comment: +1 - probably play around with it in LinqPad first, then provide the correct queries (URLs) to the editors, and presto - all your comments are belong to us.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are stored in application data, which means you can simply get to all comments by reading the right application data for each of the items (Component or Page).

The application ID for UGC comments is `ugc:ComponentAndPage`, the data will be stored as an XML document.